# PHP access class inside another class

Tags: php, variables, global

So I have two classes like this:

```
class foo {
    /* code here */
}
$foo = new foo();
class bar {
    global $foo;
    public function bar () {
        echo $foo->something();
    }
}
```

I want to access the methods of foo inside all methods bar, without declaring it in each method inside bar, like this:

```
class bar {
    public function bar () {
        global $foo;
        echo $foo->something();
    }
    public function barMethod () {
        global $foo;
        echo $foo->somethingElse();
    }
    /* etc */
}
```

I don't want to extend it, either. I tried using the var keyword, but it didn't seem to work. What do I do in order to access the other class "foo" inside all methods of bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do like this too:

```
class bar {
    private $foo = null;

    function __construct($foo_instance) {
      $this->foo = $foo_instance;
    }

    public function bar () {
        echo $this->foo->something();
    }
    public function barMethod () {
        echo $this->foo->somethingElse();
    }
    /* etc, etc. */
}
```

Later you could do:

```
$foo = new foo();
$bar = new bar($foo);
```

Comment: Never thought about passing it as a parameter; it works now. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, that's known as Dependency Injection

Comment: @John: it's too early to say someone about DI if he didn't even know about how to pass data through parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a member of bar. Try to never use globals.

```
class bar {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }

    public function barMethod() {
        echo $this->foo->something();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: nope, there is no way to implement what you want.

Another short answer: you're working with classes in "wrong" way. Once you selected Object Oriented paradigm - forget about "global" keyword.

The proper way of doing what you want is to create an instance of `foo` as member of `bar` and use it's methods. This is called `delegation`.

Answer (score 1):

And if your only focus is the methods themselves as opposed to the instance of another class, you can use `x extends y`.

```
class foo {
  function fooMethod(){
    echo 'i am foo';
  }
}

class bar extends foo {
  function barMethod(){
    echo 'i am bar';
  }
}

$instance = new bar;
$instance->fooMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to autoload your classes. Also, if you make your class a static class, you can call it without `$classname = new classname()`:

```
//Autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
$classDir = '/_class/';
$classExt = '.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $classDir . $class . $classExt;
});

//Your code
class bar {
    private static $foo = null; //to store the class instance

    public function __construct(){
        self::$foo = new foo(); //stores an instance of Foo into the class' property
    }

    public function bar () {
        echo self::$foo->something();
    }
}
```

If you convert your class (foo) into a static class

```
//Autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
$classDir = '/_class/';
$classExt = '.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $classDir . $class . $classExt;
});

//Your code
    class bar {
        public function bar () {
            echo foo::something();
        }
    }
```