# Importing variables into a class

Tags: php, class, scope

I would like to ask, if there is a way, to use variables in a class, that were declared out of it.

Example:

```
$foo = 'bar';
class foobar{
    function example(){
        echo "foo{$foo}";
    }
}
$foobar = new foobar;
$foobar->example();
```

This code produces a notice: **Notice: Undefined variable: foo**
Is there a way to make it work? Or is there some work-around?

Comment: Yes. Simply make an attribute to the class and build a constructor that sets an argument (namely the variable that you pass in) to the aforementioned attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862399/php-access-class-inside-another-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a construct to import it or use the global keyword. You could do something like this:

```
$var = 'value';
class foobar {
    private $classVar;
    function __construct($param) {
        $this->classVar = $param;
    }
}
```

And initiate it like this:

```
$var = 'value';
$inst = new foobar($var);
```

Or you can use global variables (which I wouldn't recommend in this case) and do something like this:

```
$var = 'value';
class foobar {
    global $var;
    function show() {
       echo $var;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: To use a class within another class, it may be instantiated in the constructor if its instance is needed throughout implementation, or it may be instantiated only when needed.

To create a reference to another class inside the constructor, do something like this:

```
class class1 {
    private $someVar;

    function __construct() {
        $this->someVar = 'success';
    }

    function doStuff() {
        return $this->someVar;
    }
}

class class2 {
    private $ref;
    private $val;
    function __construct() {
        $this->ref = new class1();
        $this->val = $this->ref->doStuff();
        // $this->val now holds the value 'success'
    }
}

$inst = new class2(); // upon calling this, the $val variable holds the value 'success'
```

Or you can call it only when needed, like so:

```
class class1 {
    private $someVar;

    function __construct() {
        $this->someVar = 'success';
    }

    function doStuff() {
        return $this->someVar;
    }
}

class class2 {
    private $ref;
    private $val;
    function __construct() {
        // do something
    }
    function assign() {
        $this->ref = new class1();
        $this->val = $this->ref->doStuff();
        // $this->val now holds the value 'success'
    }
}

$inst = new class2(); // the $val variable holds no value yet
$inst->assign(); // now $val holds 'success';
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I would be interested to know down-voted this answer and for what reason. I gave more than one way to accomplish the task and demonstrated how to use it instead of just giving half of the code. Some people on this site bewilder me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I find it the most complete :)

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance! I'm not sure why people on this site down-vote others for no reason, I was just trying to help. If you need any further help please just let me know and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I was playing a bit now with this newly gained knowledge and found out, that I can pass even classes like this. So I came out with: $this->foo_class->another_example() and it was actually working. However, what would be the proper way of using a different class in a class?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct. Depending on your needs, you can setup the instance of the imported class inside the constructor or you can create it only when needed. I will update my answer showing you how to do both. P.S. If you don't mind, please up-vote my answer if it was helpful, I like having a good reputation on this site. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to up-vote, but it says I need 15 reputation before I can do it :/

If I somehow get the rep, I'll be sure to come back and upvote :)

Comment: I have updated the answer now. I also up-voted your question so you should have some reputation score now. Hope that helps you, if you need anything else or if this doesn't work for you please let me know and I'd be happy to help some more!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need anymore help. If you ever need help feel free to contact me via my website at http://mdl.fm and I will be glad to help!

Comment: You cannot use `global $var;` outside of the class method like that. The line should be inside of `function show(){...}` Otherwise good answer!

Answer (score 4):

You could give this argument to your class with a constructor

```
class foobar{    

    private $foo;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->foo = $name;
    }
}
```

and then use it.

Or what PeeHaa means, you could change your method to

```
function example($param){
    echo "foo{$param}";
}
```

and call it like this

```
$foobar->example($foo);
```

Comment: Either this or inject it directly into the method that needs it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes add

```
class foobar{
    function example(){

        global $foo;

        echo "foo{$foo}";
    }
}
```

** putting it in another class is better though, or passing it to the method you're using is better too **

Comment: [Why `global`s are bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384)

Comment: This works, but is bad style, especially when used in classes.